# How to fix the 3D secure confirm Payment on client side or on server side in Stripe Payment Intent?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, stripe-payments

I'm integrating **Stripe Payment Intent API** and it's working well where 3D secure is not required, 3D secure authorization is popping up but I think I'm missing `return_url` to confirm the payment.

Where do I need to mention return_url for 3D Secure in **PaymentIntent**?

I've tried multiple times but got stuck on 3D Secure Authorize. It returns an error in the object.

I've mentioned the code of view and controller below.

Thanks in Advance

**Client Side Code:**

```
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        $('#card-button').html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" style="font-size:24px"></i>');
        var fname = $('#firstname2').val();
        var lname = $('#lastname2').val();
                    
        var cardholderName = fname + " " + lname;
        var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        var form_data = $("#payment-form").serialize();
                    
        cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
          stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
            billing_details: {name: cardholderName}
          }).then(function(result) {
            if (result.error) {
             // Show error in payment form
          } else {
             console.log(result);
             // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server (see Step 2)
             fetch('<?php echo base_url(); ?>payment/stripe_test/process_payment', 
             {
               method: 'POST',
               headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
               body: JSON.stringify({ payment_method_id: result.paymentMethod.id, customer_detail: form_data})
              }).then(function(result) {
                // Handle server response (see Step 3)
                result.json().then(function(result) {
                console.log("Response" + result);
                handleServerResponse(result);
              });
           });
          }
        });
       });
    }


    function handleServerResponse(response) {
              if (response.error) {
                // Show error from server on payment form
              } else if (response.requires_action) {
                  
                    var action = response.next_action;
                    if (action && action.type === 'redirect_to_url') {
                      window.location = action.redirect_to_url.url;
                    }
                    
                // Use Stripe.js to handle required card action
                stripe.handleCardAction(
                  response.payment_intent_client_secret
                ).then(function(result) {
                  if (result.error) {
                    // Show error in payment form
                  } else {
                    // The card action has been handled
                    // The PaymentIntent can be confirmed again on the server
                    fetch('<?php echo base_url(); ?>payment/stripe_test/process_payment', {
                      method: 'POST',
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                      body: JSON.stringify({ payment_intent_id: result.paymentIntent.id })
                    }).then(function(confirmResult) {
                      return confirmResult.json();
                    }).then(handleServerResponse);
                  }
                });
              } else {
                // Show success message
                console.log("3D" + response);
              }
            }
```

**CodeIgniter Controller:**

```
    //PaymentIntent Function
        function process_payment() {
            require_once (APPPATH."third_party/stripe/init.php");
                
            $key = "STRIPE_KEY_HERE";
            
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
            # retrieve json from POST body
            $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
            
            $intent = null;
            try {
                if (isset($json_obj->payment_method_id)) {
                  # Create the PaymentIntent
                    //STRIPE PAYMENT INTENT
                    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($key);
                    
                    // Create a Customer:
                    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
                        'email' => 'client@gmail.com',
                    ]);
                    
                    // Attach payment method to the customer:
                    
                    $customer_detail = $json_obj->customer_detail;
                    
                  $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                    'payment_method' => $json_obj->payment_method_id,
                    'amount' => 1099,
                    'currency' => 'GBP',
                    'confirmation_method' => 'manual',
                    "customer" => $customer->id,
                    'confirm' => true,
                  ]);
                }
                if (isset($json_obj->payment_intent_id)) {
                  $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve(
                    $json_obj->payment_intent_id
                  );
                  $intent->confirm();
                }
                
                $this->generatePaymentResponse($intent);
                
            } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
                # Display error on client
                echo json_encode([
                  'error' => $e->getMessage()
                ]);
            }
        }
```

**generatePaymentResponse Function:**

```
    function generatePaymentResponse($intent) {
            if ($intent->status == 'requires_source_action' &&
                $intent->next_action->type == 'use_stripe_sdk') {
              # Tell the client to handle the action
              echo json_encode([
                'requires_action' => true,
                'payment_intent_client_secret' => $intent->client_secret
              ]);
            } else if ($intent->status == 'succeeded') {
              # The payment didn’t need any additional actions and completed!
              # Handle post-payment fulfillment
              echo json_encode([
                "success" => true
              ]);
            } else {
              # Invalid status
              http_response_code(500);
              echo json_encode(['error' => 'Invalid PaymentIntent status']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi there, you don't need to specify `return_url` as PaymentIntent will use Popup as 3DS confirmation instead of redirecting. So all you need to do is in your frontend, call `stripe.handelCardAction` with the client secret. 
This function will have callback, in the callback, you would ajax to your backend again to confirm the paymentIntent. For details, check this link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/migration#payment-request-button-step-3

Comment: Thanks @wsw yeah 3D Secure popup is working but when I click Authorise Payment it returns object as an error and payment incomplete occur on Stripe Dashboard.

Comment: I’ve follow stripe document but I’m stuck on it would you please see if I’m missing any step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you don't need to specify `return_url`, because in your case Stripe will use Popup for 3DS confirmation, not redirecting.

You missed two things in your code:
1. In function `generatePaymentResponse` add condition for `$intent->status === 'requires_action'`.
2. On Payment Intent confirmation (`$intent->confirm();`) you missed to set api key (`\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($key);`)

I have tested your code and it works with mentioned modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe updated the API and few statuses were renamed so the major reason was that I was using `requires_source_action` as status so replaced it with `requires_action`.

### Stripe Update - [2019-02-11](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2019-02-11)

---

- Some PaymentIntent statuses have been renamed

  - `requires_source` is now `requires_payment_method`
  - `requires_source_action` is now `requires_action`
  - All other statuses are unchanged
- `save_source_to_customer` has been renamed to `save_payment_method.`
- `allowed_source_types` has been renamed to `payment_method_types`.
- The `next_source_action` property on `PaymentIntent` has been renamed to `next_action`, and the `authorize_with_url` within has been renamed to `redirect_to_url`.

---

You can find Stripe Api upgrades here: https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#api-versions.